# Can a datefield be set by a string value in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

Can a DateField be set by a String value?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but not directly...

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yy" );
java.util.Date dDate = df1.parse( strInput );
(DateField)yourDateField.setDate(dDate);
```